# My LESS sourceMap file is missing the "file" when run through grunt

Tags: gruntjs, less, source-maps

When I run `lessc --source-map=styles.map assets/less/00_style.less dest/assets/prod.css` in the command line, everything is working. The styles.map file ends in:

```
...AV2rEF;EAAiB,aAAA","file":"dest/assets/prod.css"}
```

However, when I run `grunt less`, the styles.map is missing the "file" part and just ends in:

```
...AV2rEF;EAAiB,aAAA"}
```

This stops the SourceMap from working. What could be going wrong? My less config is as follows:

```
less: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            sourceMapFilename: 'styles.map'
        },
        files: [{
            src : 'assets/less/00_style.less',
            dest: 'dest/assets/prod.css'
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Add the following additional option to your `less` Task in `Gruntfile.js`:

```json
...
options: {
    ...
    sourceMapURL: '../../styles.map'
},
...
```

---

**Long answer:**

When running the `lessc` command via the CLI, *(as per your example),*  notice the the following comment is written to the resultant `prod.css`:

```css
/*# sourceMappingURL=../../styles.map */
```

However, when running the `grunt` task, *(using your current config)*, the following comment is written into the resultant `prod.css`:

```css
/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.map */
```

*Note the missing `../../` - therefore `prod.css` can't find `styles.map`*

This is why your SourceMap isn't working and not so much to do with the `"file:"` missing in `styles.map` when run via `grunt`. The `.css` file ultimately points to the `.map` file - not vice versa.

Even after running the `lessc` command via the CLI then deleting the `"file:"` part from `styles.map` you will find that the SourceMap still works in the browser. Indicating that the `"file:"` part, whether included in the `.map` file or not, has no effect on preventing the SourceMap from working.

Besides, as noted in the most recent proposed SourceMap [spec](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit#heading=h.qz3o9nc69um5) (v.3) the `"file:"` part is optional:

> Line 3: An **optional** name of the generated code that this source map is associated with.

Explicitly defining the `sourceMapURL` in your grunt Task options will entail having to keep a flat folder structure inside the `dest/assets/` directory if you intend on using multiple `.less` files. *(I.e. You'll need to avoid saving any resultant `.css` files in subfolders)*